# Is there a way that i can communicate between a C++ application and a C# application?

Tags: c#, c++

Is there a way rather than using server/client approach or file save/load approach that I can use to transfer objects between two separate C++ and C# applications?

Actually what I am trying to do is that I create the GUI part of a project in C# and create some parts of the project in C++ and by communicating between these two applications I proceed and go on.

For some reasons I only want to use C++ console application (I don't know how to create a DLL in C++ and aside form that I want to know the current possibilities without using  DLLs)

Comment: You really should use DLL's. They make it sooo much simpler.

Comment: No client/server, No File Save/Load, No Dll, :)

Comment: This is achieved with marshalling.  I don't understand what you mean by not using any DLL's.  Do you want to use a console application (exe) instead of a DLL?

Comment: dll or make a console app with params and parse output over C#

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey:Yes i want to use a console application because i have no idea how i can create a dll in c++ i just want to keep it as simple as it can be

Comment: Have you considered investigating how to create a dll in C++? I believe that in Visual Studio it's just a matter of choosing the correct project type.

Comment: @Default:I also want that to be kind of portable to other platforms.In Linux we don't have Dlls,But we have c# and console applications

Comment: well, a c++ project has to be rebuilt if you're going to move it to another operating system anyway. Does [this](http://www.richelbilderbeek.nl/CppGppCreateDll.htm) help by any chance?

Comment: @Default:Thats such a neat tutorial on creating a Dll:-).Thank you again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) if they really must be separate items.

Otherwise, look into managed C++. You can create a wrapper around your C++ code and call it directly from C#. [Here's one tutorial...](http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2008/12/19/Use-C++-in-C.aspx)

Comment: Thank you but that's a .Net solution.I am more tempted to have a non.Net solution for my c++ part.

Comment: IPC is a concept, it doesn't have to be a .NET solution. Though it will require client/server.

Comment: Not true, IPC is a family of communication types. I would say it requires file (or stream) writing instead ...

Answer (score 1):

Of course a gooooood way to go would be using dlls. Also, you could create command line programs in c++ and calling them in c#. If you want to return complex data you have to implement a communication protocol.

Another way would be using a console application leaving its input opened while it processes data in another thread, this way you can handle communication streaming data (as if you open a console). Of course you need to parse the output.

Comment: command argument console applications are not good enough,because they only can get the parameters only once at the time they are executed, and while they are running i can not send more parameters to t hose applications as far as i know.So that's why I'm seeking a method for communication between two apps.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve communication between two tasks (although they've been developed in different programming languages ;-) ).

One simple way is to implement a Client/Server-Class in each application. That way you can send complex data in both directions between your tasks and let them communicate.

Comment: Read the first line in the question again: "Is there a way **rather than using server/client approach** [..]"